# close all child pop ups for a dynamic application

Tags: javascript, popup, window.open

we are using a jsp application, here we can open help window(window.open) from any page, but if that is opened we have to close it on clicking of logout, not necessarily on the same page where the help window was opened, How can i get Handler for a opened window across pages?

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me right, window.open() returns the window object, so you can simply save it to a variable.

```
var window = window.open(...);
```

or

```
var windows = [];
windows.push(window.open(...));
windows.push(window.open(...));
windows.push(window.open(...));
windows.push(window.open(...));
```

Comment: correct johan but when i go to a different jsp this varialbe is no more alive